# Type of function that removes duplicates in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function that given an array, removes the duplicate elements from it. I would like this function to work for at least number and string. My attempt is:

```
function removeDuplicates<T>(xs: T[]): T[]
{
    var res: T[] = [];
    var seen = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        var x = xs[i];
        if (!(x in seen)) {
            seen[x] = null;
            res.push(xs[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Which is valid Javascript for removing the elements (after stripping away the types). However, in TypeScript, I get the error on the `in` line saying:

> The left-hand side of an 'in' expression must be of type 'any', 'string', 'number', or 'symbol'.

I tried `T extends string | number`, but that doesn't work. I thought about `T is string | number`, but I can't find any TypeScript syntax for that. How do I capture this property in the type?

Comment: TS is giving you a red flag here appropriately, because your implementation could become wrong, i suppose. You cannot have an object as a key of another object. if you do, it will just convert the object to its string representation [object Object]. So your generic logic here will not work it T is an object, i mean the functionality itself will break. Still if you want to just make TS happy you can do var x:any = xs[i]; but that will not solve the purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use an explicit type annotation `any`:

```
function removeDuplicates<T>(xs: T[]): T[]
{
    var res: T[] = [];
    var seen = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        var x:any = xs[i];
        if (!(x in seen)) {
            seen[x] = null;
            res.push(xs[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I additionally recommend explicitly applying the `string|number` constraint:

```
type ValidKey = string|number;
function removeDuplicates<T extends ValidKey>(xs: T[]): T[]
{
    var res: T[] = [];
    var seen = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        var x:ValidKey = xs[i];
        if (!(x in seen)) {
            seen[x] = null;
            res.push(xs[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

removeDuplicates(['a','b','a']) // okay
removeDuplicates([1,2]) // okay
removeDuplicates([{a:1},{a:2}]) // Not cool
```

Comment: Is there a way you can specify constraint on `T` with Typescript ?

Comment: Awesome...   I learn a lot from your answers. Thank you, +1 !! :)